# Linking Up the Boost Package In Visual Studio C++ (2008)

Tags: visual-studio-2008, visual-c++, boost

I'm new to C++, but not C, and I'm using the [MySQL/C++ Connector package](http://dev.mysql.com/tech-resources/articles/mysql-connector-cpp.html). Running a bit sample code in a test project revealed this error:

1>c:\program files\mysql\mysql connector c++ 1.1.0\include\cppconn\connection.h(29) : fatal error C1083:
Cannot open include file: 'boost/variant.hpp': No such file or directory
(Build Log Omitted).

So clearly I need this variant.hpp file. I find the boost package, and [downloaded this binary for windows](http://www.boostpro.com/download/). I tried linking up the the dependencies in the same manner I did for the mySQL/C++ Connector, but but still get the same error. Furthermore, there doesn't appear to be any .lib files anywhere in the package. Has anyone set up this package for VS 2008 before and can help me out?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Boost variant is a header-only library. You don't need to link against it. In your project settings, add an additional include directory and set it to where boost is.

[Here's a detailed explanation with examples.](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_47_0/more/getting_started/windows.html#build-from-the-visual-studio-ide)

Comment: Thank you that was very useful. I was just one folder above that in my additional includes directory, that's why it wasn't connecting. I can't believe someone answered my question in 20 minutes. That was amazing!

Comment: @Mister Mister: Welcome to SO! And it was actually 9 minutes :)